# Android USB API does not work on all devices

Tags: android, api, usb, host

I'm developing application which talks MTP devices connected to Android device. Initially I was testing it on Asus Transformer TF101 and it worked as expected. Now I decided to test it on other tablet, namely OVO Air. Both are Android 4.0.x devices and OVO Air has OTG capability  - usb memory stick plugged into it is recognized without problems.
Unfortunately my application sees no USB devices at all on OVO Air. Following code returns empty udevs.

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> udevs = manager.getDeviceList();
```

Any ideas why it works so differently? Any drivers missing from OVO Air?

For reference code is available at http://protronika.dyndns.org/websvn-public/filedetails.php?repname=MTPBrowser&path=%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fdyndns%2Fprotronika%2Fmtpbrowser%2FBrowserView.java

Thanks in advance.